# Prevent loader from disappearing before all data is retrieved from service angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs ui-router to transition from state to state and a loader attached to each view. My problem is that when transitioning from one state to another and the loader is initiated, the loader disappears before all the contents from the web service is pulled in and other get requests completed.This is my first time trying to implement angularjs's ui-router.

I have tried to use:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$cookies){
  // fired when the transition begins.
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      $rootScope.loading = true;
  });

  // fired once the state transition is complete
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      $rootScope.loading = false;
  });
});
```

I have also tried to utilize the resolve method:

```
...
.state('loan-new',{
   url: '/loan-new/:id',
   templateUrl: BASE_URL+'js/pages/loan-new.html',
   controller: 'LoanController',
   resolve: {
      loanNew: function($q, client, $stateParams, $http) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        if(client.getAllInformation($stateParams.id) !== undefined) 
        {
          $http.get(BASE_URL+'client-loan-types').success(function(data) {

          })
          .then(function(){

            client.getAllInformation($stateParams.id).then(function(data) {
              defer.resolve(data);
              console.log('APP DATA');
              console.log(data);
            });

          });
        } 
        else 
        {
          defer.reject(data);
        }

        return defer.promise;
    }
  }
})
...
```

---

And lastly I tried the code below but to no avail.

```
app.controller('LoadingController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'client', '$q', function($scope, $http, $rootScope,  $stateParams, client, $q) {

  $rootScope.loading = true;

  // $scope.$on('LOAD', function(){$scope.loading = true});
  // $scope.$on('UNLOAD', function(){$scope.loading = false});

  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function(event, viewConfig){
     console.log('content loading: ', event, viewConfig)
     return client.getAllInformation($stateParams.id);
  });


  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
    $rootScope.loading = false;
    console.log('loaded loaded loaded');
  });
}]);
```

---

**HTML**

```
    <!-- CSS Loader -->
    <div id="overlay" ng-show="loading">
        <div class="sk-cube-grid">
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
          <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
        </div>
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>

<div class="content-wrapper ng-cloak" ng-controller="LoadingController">
    <div class="container wrap-content ng-cloak" ui-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Service**

```
app.factory('client', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q){ 
    var client = {};//empty oject that will store multiple function

 ...
 //get all of the client's personal information
 client.getAllInformation = function(ucin){
      var deferred = $q.defer(); //create promise to be completed for getting a client's information
      $http.get(LOSAPI+ucin).success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data.data); //when success resolve the promise by accepting the data from the web serivces
      }).error(function(){
           return deferred.reject(); //promise was not completed for some reason
      });
      return deferred.promise; //return the promise
 };

    return client
}]);

 ...
```

---

Any assistance with this problem will be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should `$rootScope.loading = false` after your get call has finished.

```
 client.getAllInformation = function(ucin){
      var deferred = $q.defer(); //create promise to be completed for getting a client's information
      $http.get(LOSAPI+ucin).success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data.data); //when success resolve the promise by accepting the data from the web serivces
         $rootScope.loading = false;
      }).error(function(){
           return deferred.reject(); //promise was not completed for some reason
      });
      return deferred.promise; //return the promise
 };
```

Comment: Thanks @sarvesh but this doesn't work. The web service is still being displayed seconds (3 - 5sec after) after after the loader is finished, plus there are other http services that are still being loaded behind the scenes.